# Access phpMyAdmin in cPanel?

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have a server hosted in cPanel. The url that I use to acess the File manager is:

```
www.domainname.com:2082/cpsess8363836043/frontend/x3/filemanager/index.html?dirselect=webroot&domainselect=domainname.com&dir=%2Fhome%2Fusername%2Fpublic_html&showhidden=1&saveoption=1
```

Anyhow, I am not able to access the phpMyAdmin at all. How do I acess it? Can I access it from somewhere inside the FileManager? Or is there any other URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access it from File manager. You can find another link for phpmyadmin in Cpanel home page (like FileManager)

Answer (score 0):

php myadmin is found under the databases heading in your cpanel. If it's not there, you probably need to add it.